# Answered questions not marked as "accepted" in question list

Tags: bug, design

There seems to be a styling inconsistency between the desktop and mobile web versions regarding how answered questions are displayed on the questions list.

For example, look at these two questions:

[image]

One of them has an accepted answer, and the other does not, can you tell which one? Me either.

Looking at the mobile version of the website, it is much clearer:

[image]

Bonus (imaginary) points: Is it on purpose that the "Author" shown on the mobile site is actually the last user who edited the question, and not the original author? On the desktop version, "Mitch" wrote the question, but on the mobile version it looks like Pondlife wrote it.